# Django запрос через orm не могу собрать

Tags: python, django, orm

Есть два массива

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[1,5,7]
```

Нужно сделать запрос в БД по двум полям, чтобы два раза не итерировать вот так

```
for res1 in Example.objects.using('customers').filter(Q(id_user__in=a))
    for res2 in Example.objects.using('customers').filter(Q(lessons_id__in=b))
       res2.name
```

Пытаюсь сделать так

```
Example.objects.using('customers').filter(Q(lesson_id__in=a & Q(user_id__in=b) )))
```

Как правильно?

P.S. 
по одному работает (MySQL)

```
Example.objects.using('customers').filter(Q(lesson_id__in=a))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Так правильно](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
Example.objects.using('customers').filter(Q(lesson_id__in=a), Q(user_id__in=b))
```

Comment: Спасибо я пробывал так , ко скобку потерял и думал так не заработает